# URL Rewriting in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET 4.0 URL Rewriting: How to deal with the IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060534/asp-net-4-0-url-rewriting-how-to-deal-with-the-ids)

I am trying to do url re-writing in my asp.net c# project, and I searched internet but did not get what I was looking for.

Say, for example I have following url:

```
http://www.example.com/Question.aspx?qid=1
```

Now, Question.aspx finds a question against  (which has title and body field) for qid from the db and displays it. I want to display question title in url.

My requirement is something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/Question/1/QuestionTitleGoesHere
```

Can anyone please suggest that how can I achieve this ASP.NET 4.0?

Comment: Personally, I would suggest you improve your internet searching skills. This URL rewriting example you mention is really something absolutely basic, in my opinion.

Comment: @UweKeim: My bad! I have found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060534/asp-net-4-0-url-rewriting-how-to-deal-with-the-ids
Also, I have flagged this question for deletion.

Comment: @Arry : you can also check out scott guthrie's blog... he's got some valuable tips... just providing the link incase you need it ..http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can check following working examples of URL Rewriting in asp.net web forms projects using

[URL Rewriting using ASP.NET for SEO](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33341/URL-Rewriting-using-ASP-NET-for-SEO)

[Tip/Trick: Url Rewriting with ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In IIS you can use [Url Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) to achieve this.

If you need this to be within the application, could you look at using MVC3/MVC4 instead of webforms? If that is an option.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try these links:

[URL Routing with ASP.NET 4 Web Forms (VS 2010 and .NET 4.0 Series)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)

[ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

They will help you.