# URL rewrite without folder change on condition ASPX , ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

Hi I need to change my all urls with specific keyword in between in aspx but without changing the folder structure. Right now my url and folder structure with condition are shown below:

on condition: isABC =false the url will come like `localhost55717/product/xyz.aspx` but with condition isABC =true it should come like `localhost55717/abc/product/xyz.aspx`

my folder structure are

```
project
  |_WEB
    |_Default.aspx
    |_ABC
      |_Default.aspx
    |_product
      |_xyz.aspx
```

Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060534/asp-net-4-0-url-rewriting-how-to-deal-with-the-ids

Comment: I need to rewrite url, and thats also without changing the folder structure

Comment: u have to use Routing then.

Comment: Thats the thing in mvc I can do but its a old project in aspx

Comment: u can rewrite url if you are using .net 4.0 or up 
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-URL-Routing-in-ASPNet-Web-Forms-40.aspx

Comment: Is there any other way to do this as i have many aspx pages putting each is not looking good practice also there are certain pages which are redirected somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

In your code you can specify the URL as localhost55717/abc/product/xyz.aspx wherever you are doing the redirection.

And in the web.config you can add this rule.

```
<rule name="Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="isABC" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="localhost55717/product/xyz.aspx" />
</rule>
<rule name="Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="isABC" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="localhost55717/product/xyz.aspx" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Basically we have specified the URL localhost55717/abc/product/xyz.aspx in the code and in web.config based on condition we are just rewriting the URL for server or altogether redirecting it so that its visible to client as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how I am going to put my condition isABC==true?